Why the Wordpress site language setting doesn't work?
I set the site language to English in Wordpress dashboard-setting-general-site language. But it still shows Chinese in front end, including the product archive section-read more, and the product review section. I tried to change the language to others, it still shows Chinese. I changed the theme it still has the same problem. My wordpress version is 6.4.3
Does someone know the reason? Can you help me? Thanks

What is returned in  ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
